# Display ajax in html page

Tags: html, ajax, flask

I'm using flask as a backend, and one of my endpoints is objectList, which returns data in this format:

```
[{name1:value1, name2:value2}, {name1:value3, name2:value4}]
```

In order to display this data on my html page, I'm using the following code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function){
        $.ajax({
          url: 'localhost:5000/objectList',
          method:"GET",
          success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
          };
        });
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="div1"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This doesn't display any data. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Edit: just a clarification, I want the data to load when the page loads, not on a button or a click

Comment: what is the output when you enter this url localhost:5000/objectList ? And if you do the console.log("result") , what do you get ?

Comment: The output when I enter the url is the data in the desired format. The console.log("result") just says unexpected syntax ")", so do I have an unbalanced parenthesis somewhere?

Comment: Click inspect any element in the DOM with right click, and choose "console" from the tabs where you can see the output of console.log()

Comment: The console.log("result") just says unexpected syntax ")", so do I have an unbalanced parenthesis somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I've copy-pasted the code. This is the exact error on test:5 `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'`

Comment: you still have error in the console ?  and no result in the DOM  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208756/discussion-between-megadarkfriend-and-belgacemfahmi).

Comment: array object cant display on HTML . So you need to use `JSON.stringify` for display

Comment: If your front end app is running in the flask, then you don't need to specify **http://localhost:5000** in front of url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our discussion, I find this code works properly

You have to close the parenthesis in the function ajax, and allow the access-control in the server side with this line

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

// or replace the star with the server where you have the html

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: 'localhost:5000/objectList',
          method:"GET",
          success: function(result){
           // to verifiy the result
           console.log(result);
           
           var htmlOutput = '';

           // the iteration of your result because you have many entries
           $.each(result, function(i, item) {
            htmlOutput += ''+
            '<ul>'+
             '<li>name1: '+item['name1']+'</li>'+
             '<li>name2: '+item['name2']+'</li>'+
            '</ul>';
            });
            $("#div1").html(htmlOutput);
          }, error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
           // to verifiy either there is an error or not
   console.error(textStatus);
    }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="div1"></div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("demo_ajax_json.js", function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("div").append(field + " ");
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't want it on button click, I want it to load with the page

Comment: automatic load. and go database you like this.

Comment: mean you say get data in your data base